# Hidden field returned by php is set properly but 'undefined' when getting the value with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, hidden-field

I have a javascript file posting data to php files which are suppose to get data from a mysql database, then populate fields with specified data.  When I call the php function to store the names of the fields in the database, it returns a hidden field with how many fields are in the table stored as the value to the hidden field:

```
$i = 0;
$field_names = [];    

while($i < mysql_num_fields($request)){
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($request, $i);
    $field_names[] = $field->name;

    if(!$field){
        die('something is wrong with the field var');
    };

    echo('<div class="fields" id="field_' . $i . '">' . $field->name . '<br /></div>');
        $i++;
};

    echo('<input type="hidden" value="' . $_POST['postselecttbl'] . '" id="hidden_tbl" />' .
         '<input type="hidden" value="' . count($field_names) . '" id="num_fields" />');

    $_SESSION['field_names'] = $field_names;
```

Everything appears to work.  The hidden field '#num_fields' gets set with how many fields there are.  But when I get the val() of '#num_fields' with jquery, it returns undefined until you run the function again, then it has the value from the previous time it was ran.

```
$.post('php/get_flds.php', {postdbhost: dbhost, postdbuser: dbuser, postdbpass: dbpass, postselectdb: selectdb, postselecttbl: selecttbl},
    function(d){
        $('#display_out').html(d);
    }
);

var num_flds = $('#num_fields').val();

alert('about to pop ' + num_flds);

for(var i = 0; i < num_flds; i++){
    alert('populating ' + i);
    pop_fld(i);
};
```

Is the hidden input not being set correctly?  I mean, it shows in the html code as being set, but jquery is not cooperating.

Comment: JavaScript (and ajax) is asynchronous, the post has not completed before you check for the value of the hidden field. Just put your check inside of the callback function.

Comment: Sounds like its not getting picked up as the value. Try `$('#num_fields').attr('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this hidden field called from ajax request? If so then try following:

```
$.post('php/get_flds.php', {postdbhost: dbhost, postdbuser: dbuser, postdbpass: dbpass, postselectdb: selectdb, postselecttbl: selecttbl},
    function(d){
        $('#display_out').html(d);
        var num_flds = $('#num_fields').val();

        alert('about to pop ' + num_flds);

        for(var i = 0; i < num_flds; i++){
             alert('populating ' + i);
             pop_fld(i);
        };
    }
);
```

Otherwise the jquery doesn't know the value yet as this DOM is not in the document yet.

Comment: Thank you!  My headache has subsided. :D

Answer (score -1):

Post is an asynchronous call I think. var num_fields is set BEFORE post request ends and you should update it's value when post is done.
Try something like :

```
var num_flds = $('#num_fields').val();
$.post('php/get_flds.php', {postdbhost: dbhost, postdbuser: dbuser, postdbpass: dbpass, postselectdb: selectdb, postselecttbl: selecttbl},
    function(d){
        $('#display_out').html(d);
        num_fields = $('#num_fields').val();
    }
);



alert('about to pop ' + num_flds);

for(var i = 0; i < num_flds; i++){
    alert('populating ' + i);
    pop_fld(i);
};
```

Comment: Why -1? I would appreciate understanding where I'm wrong (I know there are lot of things I have to learn yet)

Comment: This isn't going to work, your first assignment of `num_flds` does nothing since the hidden doesnt exist at all in the DOM yet. And then although you moved the assignment into the callback function, you didn't move the rest of the code, so it will still execute out of proper order.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're right, this will fail the same way since it won't wait post response. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, by the time the alerts are reached, num_flds will still be undefined.

Comment: I don't know why they gave this a -1, i haven't tried your code, but looks like it would solve the issue i was having.  The answer from Mihkel Viilveer solved my issue.  Thanks for the prompt answer though :D  BTW, I don't have enough points to vote up or down :(

Comment: Don't worry, @EkoostikMartin was right, this would fail when post response isn't fast enough to set num_fields before `for`